# php isset not working

Tags: php, string

I want to set $choice_1 and $choice_2 but only once per session. I am using $choice_1 and $choice_2 to create image names and I want to avoid drawing different jpegs within a session. I display two chess pieces at http://communitychessclub.com/rabren and I want those two images used for the entire user session.

```
<?php 
if (!isset($_SESSION['choice_1'])) {$chessmen = array("N","Q","R","B","K","P"); 

$random_piece = array_rand($chessmen); 
$choice_1 = $chessmen[$random_piece];
unset($chessmen[$random_piece]);

$random_piece = array_rand($chessmen); 
$choice_2 = $chessmen[$random_piece];} 
?>
```

Comment: So what's the issue? You are not making use of `$_SESSION` at all with the above code.

Comment: i don't see any isset()

Comment: I think before asking for help, it is good to clean your grammars first.

Comment: Yes, @Eritrea, I had an extra comma. My bad! I implemented the suggested changes but still didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use session_start() before printing any output or set session auto start to 1 in php.ini

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['test']))
echo "no test session";
else
echo $_SESSION['test'];
if($sth)
{
 $_SESSION['test'] = 'sth...';
}
```

Comment: I tried <?php session_start(); ?> but it still doesn't work. The session restarts and the variables are re-created which is not what I need.

Comment: works now! much obliged!

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way...

```
<?php 
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['choice_1'])) {
    $chessmen = array("N","Q","R","B","K","P"); 

    $random_piece = array_rand($chessmen); 
    $_SESSION['choice_1'] = $chessmen[$random_piece];

    unset($chessmen[$random_piece]);

    $random_piece = array_rand($chessmen); 
    $_SESSION['choice_2'] = $chessmen[$random_piece];
} 
?>
```

Your session data is stored inside your $_SESSION-Array and not outside as a common php variable. So if you want to - for example - print "choise_1" later, you will need to `echo $_SESSION['choise_1'];`.